# How to add an input filed to single product page in woocommerce to store extra user comments in the order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using latest wp and wc and I am trying to add a form field in the frontend single product page where the user will be able to add comments which when the order is done the data will be available under woocommerce -> orders. Have anybody done that or it's not even possible because woocommerce is pretty limited for stuff like this?